# Increasing Query Speed when joining two tables

Tags: sql, gis, geospatial, spatial

I am new to SQL and trying to speed up a query used multiple times in a stored procedure. I am trying to match the names of places using a query. Some of the places have names of different length for example the same address may be called 'McDonalds Riccarton'  in one table and 'Mac Donalds Riccarton' in another.

I have separated each of the words in each table into individual columns  ie 'McDonalds, Riccarton' and 'Mac, Donalds, Riccarton'. These are called first for first word, second for second the second word etc... as you will see in my query

By using direct comparions or using soundex I am trying to match them based on loose matching terms for example where the soundex (mac) = soundex(macdonalds) 
          and  soundex (riccarton) = soundex( riccarton) they should be the same.

The query tries to match first word to all other columns ie first match first or second or third or fourth or last... last is the last word or any groups of words that are longer than the fourth word for long sets of names..

I am happy with my current query except that it is a little slow. When matching tables with 50 names in one and 600 names in another it takes roughly 2 mins. it obviously must be trying to match in each of the 'or' loops until it falls over and then tries the next loop... making it slow. I would like to avoid cursors if possible. Cheers in advance.

```
insert into 
         dbo.MatchedCulture_Recreation_Sports
select 
    loc.id, 
    loc.name, 
    cpn.cpn_id,
    cpn.cpn_name
from    
    #NZF_CPN_Culture_Recreation_Sports cpn
inner join  #Locations_Culture_Recreation_Sports loc
    on 
                                    (
    --where they match in string size see if the names match exactly
                                         (

                                            cpn.stringsize = loc.stringsize and
                                            cpn.first = loc.first and 
                                            loc.last = cpn.last and 
                                            cpn.second = loc.second and 
                                            cpn.third = loc.third and 
                                            cpn.fourth = loc.Fourth
                                        )
                                    or 

    --or where they arent equal and the name isnt one word
                                        (
                                            cpn.stringsize <> loc.stringsize and
                                            cpn.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                            loc.stringsize <>1  and 
                                    (

    --  see if the first word matches anything
                                        cpn.first = loc.first or
                                        cpn.first = loc.second or 
                                        cpn.first = loc.third or 
                                        cpn.first = loc.fourth or 
                                        cpn.first = loc.last
                                    ) 
                                    and 

    --  and the last word matches anything
                                    (
                                        cpn.last = loc.first or  
                                        cpn.last =  loc.second or 
                                        cpn.last =  loc.third or 
                                        cpn.last = loc.fourth or 
                                        cpn.last = loc.last
                                    ) 
                                    and 

    --  and the sec matches anything
                                    (
                                        cpn.second = loc.first or
                                        cpn.second = loc.second or 
                                        cpn.second = loc.third or 
                                        cpn.second = loc.fourth or 
                                        cpn.second = loc.last
                                    ) 
--  or if the there are 3 words in one and 2 words in another try soundex
                                )
                            or 
                                (
                                    cpn.stringsize = 2 and 
                                    loc.stringsize = 3 and
                                    cpn.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    loc.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.last)
                                    ) 

                                    )
--  or if the there are 3 words in the other and 2 words in one try soundex
                            or 
                            (
                                    cpn.stringsize = 3 and 
                                    loc.stringsize = 2 and
                                    cpn.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    loc.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.last)
                                    ) 

                                        )
                                    or 
--  or if the there are more than 3 words in one and 3 words in another try soundex
                                (
                                        cpn.stringsize <3 and 
                                        loc.stringsize = 3 and
                                        cpn.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                        loc.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.third) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.first) = SOUNDEX(cpn.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.second) = SOUNDEX(cpn.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.second) = SOUNDEX(cpn.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.second) = SOUNDEX(cpn.third) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.second) = SOUNDEX(cpn.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.third) or
                                        SOUNDEX(loc.last) = SOUNDEX(cpn.last)
                                    ) 

                                    )
                                    or 
--  or if the there are 3 words in the other and 3 words in one try soundex
                            (
                                    cpn.stringsize = 3 and 
                                    loc.stringsize < 3 and
                                    cpn.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    loc.stringsize <> 1 and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.third) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.first) = SOUNDEX(loc.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.second) = SOUNDEX(loc.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.second) = SOUNDEX(loc.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.second) = SOUNDEX(loc.third) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.second) = SOUNDEX(loc.last)
                                    ) 
                                    and 
                                    (
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.first) or
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.second) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.third) or 
                                        SOUNDEX(cpn.last) = SOUNDEX(loc.last)
                                    ) 

                                            )
                                    )
                                    and
-- search within a distance
                                    (
                                        loc.latitude < cpn.Maxlat and 
                                        loc.latitude > cpn.Minlat and
                                        loc.longitude < cpn.Maxlon and 
                                        loc.longitude > cpn.Minlon 
                                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try execution plan [image: Icon of execution plan]in `SQL Server Management Studio`. It let you know missing index (if it need index) list with a index creation script in sql. After creating index the query will run more faster then before.

That is the one way to speed up your query in `SQL Server`.

Comment: Cheers I am aware of this have had problems because its a stored procedure with input variables it either acts up and says there are errors with the code (that don't normaly exist) or when i run it as a stored procedure it obviously doesn't see a need to build an index for a SP.